# Prove that $|S_A|=n!$

Tags: combinatorics

Let $ A $ be a finite set with $ n $ elements. Define $ S_A $ the set of all bijective functions from $ A $ to $ A $.

To prove that its cardinal is $ n! $ I will prove it by mathematical induction.

For $ n = 1 $, then $ A $ has only one element, therefore there is only one bijective function from $ A $ to $ A $. That is, $ | S_A | = 1 = 1! $.

Let $ A $ be a set with $ n $ elements such that $ | S_A | = n! $. Let $ B $ be a set with $ n + 1 $ elements. Let $ S_B $ be the set of all bijective functions from $ B $ to $ B $. Furthermore, we can represent $ B$ as follows: $$ B = \{b_1, \ldots, b_ {n + 1} \}. $$

We are going to classify the elements of $ S_B $ as follows, $$ (S_B) _i = \{f \in S_B \mid f (b_ {n + 1}) = b_i \} $$
for all $ 1 \leq i \leq n + 1 $. How could I prove that $ | (S_B) _i | = n! $ And $ S_B = \bigcup_ {i = 1} ^ {n + 1} (S_B) _i $? Someone could help me with those two incisions that I have left, and tell me if the demonstration is good or if I have a wrong step.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof works perfectly so far and you are very close to getting your answer. First, note that $(S_B)_i$ has the same cardinal as the set $\{f: \{b_1, \dots, b_n\} \rightarrow B \setminus \{b_i\}: f \text{ bijective}\}.$ Thus $\# (S_B)_i$ is just the number of bijective functions from a set with $n$ elements to a set with $n$ elements, i.e. $n!$ by the induction hypothesis. Morever, we indeed have that $S_B = \bigcup_{1 \leq i \leq n} (S_B)_i$ (and this union is a disjoint union). Indeed, the reverse inclusion is immediate and the direct one is also immediate since any $f \in S_B$ is an element of $(S_B)_{j_f},$ where $j_f$ is defined by $b_{j_f} = f(b_{n + 1}).$ I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thank you, your answer gave me a lot of encouragement, since this test has been quite hard for me. What's more. Thank you for the help you gave me, and finally after a long time and with your help I can finish that exercise.

Comment: No worries, it's my pleasure! :)